# Javascript/Jquery toggle though objects with event

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, toggle, aframe

I have an aframe-scene with two arrows and some objects and i try to toggle through the objects, but i dont get it right some help would be nice here what i got:

```
  AFRAME.registerComponent("fool", {
    init: function() {
        var boxarray = ["#bluebox, #yellowbox, #greenbox]

        boxarray[0] = true;

        if(boxarray[0] = true){
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('visible', 'true');
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('scale', {x:1,y:1,z:1});
        } else {
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('visible', 'false');
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('scale', {x:0,y:0,z:0});
        }

        if(boxarray[1] = true){
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('visible', 'true');
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('scale', {x:1,y:1,z:1});
        } else {
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('visible', 'false');
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('scale', {x:0,y:0,z:0});
        }

        if(boxarray[2] = true){
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('visible', 'true');
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('scale', {x:1,y:1,z:1});
        } else {
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('visible', 'false');
          document.getElementById('bluebox').setAttribute('scale', {x:0,y:0,z:0});
        }

      function toggleright(){
?help?
      }

      function toggleleft(){
?help?
      }
      })
```

I try to give all of my objects(boxes) an event so changing source is just useful if the event changes too

Comment: you need to do `if( boxarray[x] === true)`. Doing a single `=` is an assignment

Comment: it needs to be done differently, as you overwrite the string array with bools (or compare strings with bools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having one method which will toggle the "next" entity visible, and the "previous" one invisible.

This way, your left / right method will only determine which one should be next and use the toggling function.

It could be done with a component like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
 init: function() {
  this.objects = ["one", "two", "three"]
  this.iterator = 0
  this.left = AFRAME.utils.bind(this.left, this);
  this.right = AFRAME.utils.bind(this.right, this);
 },
 right: function() {
  let i = (this.iterator - 1) < 0 ? this.objects.length - 1 : this.iterator - 1
  this.toggle(this.iterator, i)
 },
 left: function() {
  let i = (this.iterator + 1) >= this.objects.length ? 0 : this.iterator + 1
  this.toggle(this.iterator, i)
 },
 toggle: function(oldEl, newEl) {
  document.getElementById(this.objects[oldEl]).setAttribute("visible", "false")
  document.getElementById(this.objects[newEl]).setAttribute("visible", "true")
  this.iterator = newEl
 }
})
```

The `right` and `left` methods only check if there we didn't reach the beginning / end of the array, and call the `toggle` method which switches the visibility.

Live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bw3ks67x/23/).

Comment: works perfect thx <3 ya. You are the good samaritan of stack :D

Comment: @Delidragon i'm glad i could help, I hope it's quite clear :)